# Example equation which does not have a closed-form solution

Tags: closed-form, elementary-functions

Can you give an example equation which does not have a closed-form solution?

And when should I suspect that a given equation has no closed-form solution?

Usually the question asked is whether a certain kind of equation can be solved in closed form. Now I ask a more general question.

Comment: Perhaps something like $x+\sin(x)=1$?  Its solution is close to $0.5109734293885691$

Comment: $x=\cos(x)$ is one of them

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'equation'? $f(x)=\int e^{-x^2}dx$ is an example of a function with no closed form, is this what you have in mind?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx/4390291#4390291) for a closed form with mathematica functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["Closed form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) means you've given which symbols, functions and operations are allowed. Usually, "in closed form" means in finite terms of rational numbers, algebraic operations, [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and/or [Special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions).

Therefore it's not possible to say that a given equation doesn't have a closed-form solution. Instead, we have to ask whether the equation has solutions in a given class of functions.
$\ $

For indefinite integration of elementary functions by elementary functions, we have [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) with [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).
Solvability of differential equations in certain classes of functions (e.g. Elementary functions, [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function), Special functions) are treated in Differential Galois theory and in Differential algebra.

A part of the answer is: equations that don't have a solution cannot be solved in closed form.
$\ $

Let's restrict ourselves to equations in the complex numbers of one unknown and functions in the complex numbers.
The solutions of such equations are numbers. We have to look for [closed-form numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number) therefore. Among other things, the *explicit* algebraic numbers and the *explicit* elementary numbers are closed-form numbers (see below).

Consider that the function symbols in an equation actually mean **functions** and that certain functions have certain domains and certain ranges.

Consider that the function terms of each of the elementary standard functions (sin, cos, tan, cot, sec, csc, sinh, cosh, tanh, coth, sech, csch, arcsin, arccos, arctan, arccot, arcsec, arccsc, arcsinh, arccosh, arctanh, arccoth, arcsech, arccsch) can be brought to an  algebraic-$\exp$-$\ln$-form.
So the function term of a trigonometric or hyperbolic function can be represented as a non-constant rational expression over the algebraic numbers of $e^{iz}$ or of $e^z$ respectively.
See e.g. the Wikipedia articles for the single functions or [Abramowitz/Stegun 1970].

[Abramowitz/Stegun 1970] Abramowitz, M.; Stegun, I.: Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables. National Bureau of Standard 1970

**1.) Range of functions**

The existence of a solution can depend on the ranges of the functions in the equation.

Examples:

$$\sqrt{z}=-c\ \ \ \ (c>0)$$

$$\arcsin(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}+c\ \ \ \ (c>0)$$

Let $f$ a function of one variable. The situation doesn't change if you apply injective functions to the equation:

$$a+b\sqrt{z}=a-cb\ \ \ \ (c>0)$$

$$\ln(\sqrt{z})=\ln(-c)\ \ \ \ (c>0)$$

**2.) Solutions by radicals**

The numbers that can be represented by radical terms are called the *explicit* algebraic numbers. For [solving algebraic equations by radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_solution), we have [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) with Galois theory. Consider that each equation of the kind $A(x)=0$ ($A$ an algebraic function) leads to an algebraic equation.

There are criteria for determining whether a given quintic is solvable by radicals. see e.g. [Wikipedia: Quintic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function)

Example:

$$1-z+z^5=0$$

Let $f$ a function of one variable. The situation doesn't change if you apply functions to $z$ and/or to the equation:

$$\cos(1-f(z)+f(z)^5)=1$$

**3.) Solutions by algebraic numbers**

Algebraic functions have algebraic values for each of its algebraic arguments. And certain transcendental functions have empty [exceptional sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function#Exceptional_set) (see my answer at [On the behavior of transcendental functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000638/on-the-behavior-of-transcendental-functions/3889240#3889240)).
Let $A$ an algebraic function and $T$ a transcendental function. Equations of the kind

$$T(z)=A(z)\tag{1}$$

have algebraic solutions only at the exceptional points of $T$. If the exceptional set of $T$ is empty, the equation cannot have algebraic solutions therefore.

Example:

$$\cot(z)=z$$

Let $f$ a function of one variable. The situation doesn't change if you apply functions to $z$ and/or to the equation:

$$\sin(\cot(f(z)))=\sin(f(z))$$

An equation having no algebraic solutions doesn't have *explicit* algebraic solutions.

There are other closed-form representations for algebraic numbers (e.g. Bring radicals and theta functions). see e.g. [Wikipedia: Quintic function - Beyond radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Beyond_radicals).

**4.) Solutions by elementary [partial inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses)**

Let $E$ an elementary function. Solving an equation

$$E(z)=0\tag{2}$$

by rearranging it by operations we can read from the equation means applying the partial inverse functions of $E$. The incomprehensibly unfortunately hardly noticed theorem in [Ritt 1925], that is proved also in [Risch 1979], implies what kinds of elementary functions can have elementary partial inverses.

The elementary functions are generated from their complex function variable by applying finite numbers of $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or **unary or multiary** algebraic functions. The elementary functions having elementary partial inverse functions are generated from their complex function variable by applying finite numbers of $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or **unary** algebraic functions.

Let
$n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}$,
$A$ a non-zero algebraic function of $n$ variables without univariate factors,
$f_1,...,f_n$ algebraically independent elementary functions of one variable.
Equations of the kind

$$A(f_1(z),...,f_n(z))=0\tag{3}$$

possibly don't have an elementary partial inverse function therefore. That means, such equations possibly cannot be *rearranged* by applying only elementary functions we can read from the equation.

Examples:

$$A(z,e^z)=0$$

$$A(z,\ln(z))=0$$

$$A(z,e^z,\ln(z))=0$$

$$A(z,\sin(z))=0$$

But consider the exceptional points of the functions on the left-hand sides of the equations.

Let $f$ an elementary function of one variable. The situation doesn't change if you apply elementary functions to $z$ and/or functions to the equation:

$$a+bA(f(z),\sin(f(z)))=a$$

$$\cos(A(f(z),\sin(f(z))))=1$$

The method presented in [Khovanskii 2014] and articles of A. Khovanskii and Y. Burda can prove for individual given elementary functions whether they have elementary partial inverse functions or not. [Belov-Kanel/Malistov/Zaytsev 2020] proves that the equation

$$\tan(z)-z=a\ \ \ \ \ (a\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$$

cannot be solved by rearranging it by applying only elementary functions readable from the equation.

The algebraic functions are subdivided into the explicit algebraic functions and the implicit algebraic functions. The elementary functions are therefore subdivided into the explicit elementary functions and the implicit elementary functions. An elementary function having no elementary partial inverse function don't have *explicit* elementary partial inverse functions.

[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[Khovanskii 2014] Khovanskii, A.: Topological Galois Theory. Solvability and Unsolvability of Equations in Finite Terms. Springer 2014

[[Belov-Kanel/Malistov/Zaytsev 2020] Belov-Kanel, A.; Malistov, A.; Zaytsev, R.: Solvability of equations in elementary functions. Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications 29 (2020) (2) 204-205](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.10409)

**5.) Solutions by elementary numbers**

The [Elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) ([see also](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryNumber.html)) are generated by applying a finite number of elementary functions (see above) to the rational numbers.

For the exponential polynomials, we have the main theorem of [Lin 1983]:
If Schanuel's conjecture is true, an equation $P(x,e^x)=0$ with $P(X,Y)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(X,Y)$ an irreducible polynomial involving $X$ and $Y$ cannot have a solution $x\neq 0$ that is an elementary number.

Example:

$$z+\sin(z)=0$$

Let $f$ an elementary function of one variable. The situation doesn't change if you apply elementary functions to $z$ or functions to the equation:

$$a+bA(f(z),\sin(f(z)))=a$$

$$\cos(A(f(z),\sin(f(z))))=1$$

An equation having no elementary solutions don't have *explicit* elementary solutions.

In [A conjecture about the solvability of rational equations of transcendental functions by elementary numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752090/a-conjecture-about-the-solvability-of-rational-equations-of-transcendental-funct), I present an extension of Lin's theorem that I meanwhile have proven.

[Chow 1999] presents a method for this problem for the *explicit* elementary numbers.

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

**6.) Solutions by Lambert W and elementary functions**

Let $f$ an elementary function of one variable. According to Lin's theorem (see above), irreducible algebraic equations over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of simultaneously $f(z)$ and $e^{f(z)}$ don't have an elementary solution except $f(z)=0$.

The non-elementarity of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) has been proven already by Liouville. Lambert W is the inverse relation of the function $F\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},z\mapsto ze^z$. Lambert W can therefore be used for solving equations that lead to equations of the kind $f_0(f_1(z)e^{f_2(z)})=f_0(y)$, wherein $f_0,f_1,f_2$ are functions of one variable, $f_1=f_2$ and $y$ is a complex variable or a complex constant.

Let
$a,b,c$ complex constants,
$f$ a function of one variable with appropriate partial inverse functions in closed-form,
$y$ a complex variable or complex constant.

Equations of the kind $(a+bf(z))^ce^{f(z)}=y$ can be solved by only Lambert W, elementary functions and appropriate partial inverse functions of $f$. Equations that lead to algebraic equations over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of simultaneously $f(z)$ and $e^{f(z)}$ that aren't of the above kind of equations are candidates for equations not solvable using only Lambert W, elementary functions and appropriate partial inverse functions of $f$.

Example:

$$(1+z+z^2)e^z=y$$

Equations where $f_1$ is a non-constant non-polynomial rational function of $z$ and $f_2$ is a non-constant polynomial function of $z$ or vice versa are such candidates.

Example:

$$\frac{z}{1+z}e^z=y$$

The situations don't change if you apply functions to $z$ and/or to the equations.

Equations of the kind

$$f_0(R_1(f(z))e^{R_2(f(z))})=f_0(y),$$

wherein $R_1(f(z)),R_2(f(z))$ are non-constant rational expressions of $f(z)$ can be solved in closed form by only generalized Lambert W ([Mezö/Baricz 2017]), elementary functions and appropriate partial inverse functions of $f$.

[[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

**7.) Solutions by Generalized Lambert W or Hyper Lambert W and elementary functions**

Addionally, we could collect criteria for which equations are not solvable in terms of elementary functions together with Generalized Lambert W or Hyper Lambert W.
see [How to check if some equation can be solved using Lambert $\operatorname{W}$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048034/how-to-check-if-some-equation-can-be-solved-using-lambert-operatornamew-fun/2529537#2529537)

**8.) Solutions by the functions of Leal and coworkers**

Additionally, we could collect criteria for which equations are not solvable in terms of elementary functions together with functions presented in
[[Vazquez-Leal et al. 2020] Vazquez-Leal, H.; Sandoval-Hernandez, M. A.; Filobello-Ninoa, U.: The novel family of transcendental Leal-functions with applications to science and engineering. Heliyon 6 (2020) (11) e05418](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405844020322611).

$\ $

See also [Trigonometric/polynomial equations and the algebraic nature of trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082103/trigonometric-polynomial-equations-and-the-algebraic-nature-of-trig-functions/2360854#2360854).